# converted py to exe using pyinstaller but when run it getting openpyxl module missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I did pyinstaller --onefile main.py in command prompt

This made the exe in a folder called dist where my project is which I then ran in command prompt and got the error below:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49451/devtools/browser/b4cedddd-0d98-4929-8fdb-b92d174992cc
[18704:11556:1103/114958.968:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:49:58.968] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[18704:11556:1103/114958.968:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:49:58.968] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 138, in import_optional_dependency
File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "openpyxl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 9, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "openpyxl\worksheet\_write_only.py", line 13, in <module>
File "openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 23, in init openpyxl.worksheet._writer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.cell._writer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
import newspapers as np
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "newspapers.py", line 16, in <module>
from constants import driver
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "constants.py", line 9, in <module>
df = pd.read_excel('MOPI Template News & Mags.xlsx', sheet_name='Passwords')
File "pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
File "pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
File "pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1419, in __init__
File "pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 524, in __init__
File "pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 141, in import_optional_dependency
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
[2500] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I'm using python version 3.10 - i coded this program in a virtual environment where i have all the modules. When i run pip list it shows I do have openpyxl 3.0.10.

I saw a suggestion to try update the auto generated spec file and use hidden_imports variable for the modules that are missing - so I followed a video online which advised to update lines so had below added/amended:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hidden_imports = collect_submodules('openpyxl')
hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
```

I got the exact same error after trying this.

The program runs fine when in PyCharm but not when run this exe I've created. I also made sure to try run using the terminal in PyCharm too. Any ideas why I'm still getting this error?

Comment: create an [example]

Answer (score 1):

1. When you open the `dist` folder, do you see the `openpyxl` module? If not, try to do it via the `add-data` or `hidden-import`. Or even easier, just copy paste it manually and see if that works. Like `pyinstaller file.py --hidden-import=openpyxl`
2. You could either try updating your [pyhooks-contrib](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib) as it could have been fixed

Comment: hi, yeah when i ran pyinstaller file.py --hidden-import=openpyxl -  I did have a folder for openpyxl which had two sub folders with Python Extension Module (.pyd) files. But still have the same error message showing up on the terminal when run though.

Comment: Are you running on a different location, or from the same root folder?

Comment: I'm running from the dist folder the main.exe went to (openpyxl folder in same directory) but getting same openpyxl ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: this worked for me. Thank YOU ! --hidden-import="openpyxl.cell._writer"

Comment: The command above worked also for the package eel whichs uses pyinstaller. Thanks